# Adding attribute at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible to add a required attribute on runtime in a textbox? I want to do validation with JS n Jquery. But my requirement is that i can not hard code required attribute. I need it to get generate on runtime.

Comment: have you tried or even search anything? Use `attr()` for instance

Comment: Kindly share what you tried ?

Comment: what you tried so far show us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
// To set attribute
jQuery("#id_of_element").attr("My_attribute","Value");

// To get attribute
jQuery("#id_of_element").attr("My_attribute");
```

Answer (score 3):

Said not to see what you have tried so far, you find many tutorials about this.

Use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set attributes on elements

```
$('input').attr('required', true);
```

Another solution from jQuery 1.6 is using the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function:

```
$('input').prop('required', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Method:

```
$("#hello").attr("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code and try.

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```